# Каким образом можно управлять железом из Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем доброго времени суток. Начал изучать Python 3.x, и начал читать книгу, в ней сказано, что на Python можно даже роботов программировать, но в книги об этом ничего не сказано. Яндекс мне тоже ничего стоящего не предложил, так вот, можете сказать как с помощью Python управлять железом, даже не надо роботов, а хотя бы просто по команде включать диод и выключать его? Хотя бы в какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 5):

Должна быть библиотека для python, через которую вы можете осуществлять взаимодействие с устройством. Но это, в принципе, верно для любого языка.

python и RaspberryPi https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/python/
python и Arduino http://playground.arduino.cc/interfacing/python

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том, что Python - полнофункциональный, интерпретируемый язык.

Так что если на какой-либо системе есть возможность запуска интерпретатора Python и загружен код программы, то эту программу можно запустить на этой системе.

Возможности программы в этом случае будут ограничены только интерфейсами, к которым интерпретатору будет разрешён доступ.

Есть также возможность компилировать Python в исполняемые файлы, но не уверен, что такой подход используется в интересующих вас случаях (могу ошибаться).

---

Не обязательно даже запускать приложение Python непосредственно на интересующем устройстве. Иногда устройства управляются через проводные/безпроводные интерфейсы. В таком случае вам нужно найти лишь нужную библиотеку (или написать самому, разобравшись со стандартами передачи информации этого устройства) и использовать её для своих программ на Python.

---

Думаю, если вас интересует этот момент, стоит начать с поиска платформы, на которой вести разработку. Притом выбирать платформы, которые поддерживают запуск скриптов на Python или имеют библиотеки с реализованным интерфейсом передачи данных.

В плане работы с устройствами Python ничем не отличается от других полноценных языков программирования.

Answer (score 2):

Вот вам направление для копания:

- [Библиотека для работы с GPIO на Intel Galileo и Intel Edison](https://github.com/emutex/wiring-x86)
  Там есть пример мигания светодиодом на питоне
- [Вот ещё пример для Intel Edison](http://www.instructables.com/id/Getting-Started-with-Intel-Edison-Python-Programin/?ALLSTEPS)